# How to change removeUrl of Kendo UI upload async in onSuccess?

Tags: kendo-ui

I'm using upload async to upload files via ajax, and I need to update the removeUrl based on the idea of the uploaded file which returns from server after insert in database, how can I do this? it seems there is no method for changing that in api documentations, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`e.sender.options.async.removeUrl` is where the removeUrl is. Just change it to whatever suits your needs. Like this

```
function onSuccess(e) 
{
       if (e.operation == "upload")
       {
          //do your stuff, server response is in e.response
          e.sender.options.async.removeUrl ="newUrl";
       }
}
```

If you're uploading many files at once and want to set `removeUrl` for each one to be different, then the simplest approach would be to store server response from `success` somewhere, tap into `remove` event and change the `removeUrl` there.